# How to call cart items in the admin?

Tags: magento

I am trying to customize a module, and need to call the cart items inside a model from the backend (adminhtml) while creating an order from backend. `Calling Models('checkout/session'), ('checkout/cart')`, and helper doesnot seem to work. Does `getCustomercart()` works or shall I try anything else ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For backend orders you have access to the 'quote' object like this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session_quote')->getQuote().
```

See what else you can use from the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Model_Sales_Order_Create`. That's the model that handles the backend order creation.